# Convert daily data to quarterly which gives the data point of the last date of that quarter

Tags: r, excel

The following is the format of the data

```
01-Jan-1996 2.921090269

02-Jan-1996 2.950562989

03-Jan-1996 2.943103392

04-Jan-1996 2.935351262

05-Jan-1996 2.944054125

08-Jan-1996 2.973526845

09-Jan-1996 3.017918758

10-Jan-1996 3.010166628
```

I want to convert the above to quarterly in r/excel with the entries being for the last date of the quarter only and not the sum/average etc.

Comment: So you want to keep only the data for the last day of each quarter?

Comment: @iod yes only the last day of the quarter, and please remember that the last day does not necessarily mean the last date of quarter. Thanks.

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up:

```
library(dplyr)
dd<-read.table(text="Date        Number
01-Jan-1996 2.921090269
02-Jan-1996 2.950562989
03-Jan-1996 2.943103392
04-Jan-1996 2.935351262
05-Jan-1996 2.944054125
08-Jan-1996 2.973526845
09-Jan-1996 3.017918758
10-Jan-1996 3.010166628", header=T)
```

Make the date column into actual `Date`:

```
dd$Date<-as.Date(dd$Date,format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

Keep only the last date for each Quarter:

```
dd<- dd %>% mutate(Q=cut.Date(Date, "quarter", labels=F)) %>% 
     group_by(Q) %>% filter(Date==max(Date))
```

Comment: It gives me an error "could not find function "%>%" ".

Comment: Right, forgot to mention this uses `dplyr`.

Comment: The commands are working but it deletes everything else except the last year's quarter data. The appended file only has the latest year's quarter data.

Comment: gch... I thought lubridate::quarter works differently. Amended my solution. Now it should work for multiple years.

Comment: what? What happens after you do the dd$Q<-lubridate... line? Doesn't it add a Q column to your dd?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works. It was very helpful of you. I was making a mistake, my bad. :D

Comment: OK, dropped the lubridate altogether. This should work for sure.

Comment: No No the earlier lubridate solution was working, you did not need to change it. :D

Comment: yeah, well, it's better without it. :)